# HttpHandler for prefix in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I am trying to convert http call in aspx to https

Back Ground : i have a Aspx page that is in https site.on that page i have reference to script of google

Aspx page reference :

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i have created a HttpHandler for Prefix Http 
IHttpHandler Interface implementation :

```
public class HttpToHttpsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("http:"))
            {
                string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace("http", "https");
                context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config file registration code :

```
  <httpHandlers>

    <add verb="*" path="http:*" type="HttpToHttpsHandler , App_Code"/>

  </httpHandlers>
```

But i am not getting the control in Http handler class.what could be the possible error.

Comment: whenever I create a handler, I create a folder named handlers off the main web directory and create a "generic" handler (.ashx).  I call the handler from js, "/handlers/nameOfHandler.ashx?arg1=121212"  ...

Comment: Do you want to set the URL in the `<script>` tag on the page to HTTPS? Because if so using an HttpHandler won't do that because no browser will request that script from your server. The absolute easiest way to auto force scripts to resolve to http or https based on the parent page is to set the `src` as `src=//the.url.com`. Browsers will automatically insert `http:` or `https:` before the `//` depending on what the page loaded as. This works with all types of absolute urls, hrefs, img src, etc.

Comment: I agree with @siva.k ... You don't need (or want) a handler to do this for you. Just reference your script with the // as described and you'll get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if your assembly is called "App_Code". In your type declaration you must enter the assembly name, not the folder name of the C# file.

Comment: What could be my assembly Name. Is it my project name

Comment: You can find it in the Properties Page of your project, and is usually your project name.

Comment: Did it work? This problem isn't your main problem with this code as suggested by others, but at least will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The **path** attribute as far as I know it is relative position and it only can take one of two values: the name/file-name or the extension/file-extension to map. Like

```
      <add verb="*" path="*.SampleFileExtension" 
         type="Example1 " />
```

Or

```
      <add verb="*" path="demo.*" 
         type="Example1 " />
```

I tried a combination of both these and it also worked, which says that anything that starts with **test** and for any extension will be handler by handler:

```
 <add  verb="*" path="test*.*"
                  name="HelloWorldHandler"
                  type="demo.HelloWorldHandler,App_Code" />
```

But please notice that it is a relative path, so it means it does not include the **http** or **https** values from the URL and therefore a Handler cannot be used to validate URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your assembly name which contains the `HttpToHandler` class.
The handler is defined as the class `HttpToHttpsHandler` in the your assembly which if is in the same project then it will be your application name.
Go through this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" 
         type="HttpToHttpsHandler , AssemblyName" />
    </httpHandlers> 
  </system.web>
```

---

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

`HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection` Property determines whether the `HTTP` connection uses secure sockets ( HTTPS) or not .-[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: But will it catch the request made to google apis from aspx page in http handler class